# Слишком медленный интернет на Linux Ubuntu 22

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Я неопытный юзер Линукс, скачал недавно Ubuntu 22. Столкнулся с проблемой - проводной интернет по Ethernet работает слишком медленно. Причем, на Windows все было прекрасно. Когда включаю компьютер, то интернет слишком медленный - 0.5-1 mbps, после я делаю перезагрузку, и он на 5 минут повышается до 80-90 mbps и падает обратно до начального уровня. Испробовал все, что нашел на сайтах.

```
$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network                 
       описание: Ethernet interface
       продукт: RTL-8100/8101L/8139 PCI Fast Ethernet Adapter
       производитель: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.

$ lspci -knn | grep Eth -A2
06:01.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL-8100/8101L/8139 PCI Fast Ethernet Adapter [10ec:8139] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL-8100/8101L/8139 PCI Fast Ethernet Adapter [10ec:8139]
    Kernel driver in use: 8139too
    Kernel modules: 8139cp, 8139too
```

Попробовал установить 8168, но, когда я пытаюсь сделать его главным вместо 8139, то говорит отказано в доступе даже с помощью sudo.

Помогите, пожалуйста.
Спасибо.

Comment: фирмваре стоит?

Comment: нужен кусок  dmesg  когда линукс нашел сетевушку и посмотреть кусок где сеть начинает тупить

Comment: у вас подгрузились два модуля 8139cp и 8139too, попробуйте один из них выгрузить. Как вариант гляньте эту [темку](https://serverfault.com/questions/480217/how-do-i-disable-8139too-network-driver-in-favor-of-the-8139cp-network-driver-in).